# Is useSession/getSession really serverless in next-auth?

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, next.js, google-cloud-run, next-auth

One thing I can't wrap my head around considering using [next-auth](https://next-auth.js.org/) is if useSession/getSession really is serverless. If I understand it correctly useSession/getSession is the glue for data-availability within next-auth. I know what sessions are but for me they are entirely tied to an individual server. Hence my confusion with next-auth [claiming to be built for serverless](https://next-auth.js.org/) and useSession/getSession being such key figures in the documentation.

Since I want to deploy my app to Cloud Run I'm wondering what happens with the session if a new instance is created? Since I also need the user to be able to have access to the access-token for calls to Google-Analytics API, this is crucial for me to know before starting development :)

Could it be that the "next-auth.session-token" stored in my browser re-generates the session? I don't want people to automatically be logged out when a new instance is created.

Since I can't find any official documentation around this or can't find the spot in the [source on github](https://github.com/nextauthjs), I'm a bit lost here. Do any of you guys know?

Can I just rely on useSession/getSession no matter what when I deploy to cloud run?

This link covers useSession and getSession: https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/example

It would really mean the world to me if any knowledgable person could answer this question since I'm stuck here :)

Comment: The session is not saved in a server. NextAuth.js persists the user's session either in a JWT (default) or a database (if you're using a database adapter).

Comment: Perfect :) Big thanks for your help and reply @juliomalves